# Cloud SQL import permissions issues for Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am writing a Cloud Function to:

- [Export](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/sqladmin_v1beta4.instances.html#export) a Cloud SQL (postgresql) DB to a file in a Cloud Storage bucket
- [Import](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/sqladmin_v1beta4.instances.html#import_) it back into another Cloud SQL instance/DB (still postgresql)

**Note:**
I want this code to run on its own every night to copy a production DB to a staging environment, so I'm planning to trigger it using Cloud Scheduler.
If you have a better/easier solution to pull this out within GCP I'm all ears :)

Here's my code (the actual function is `clone_db` at the bottom of the file):

```py
from os import getenv
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.cloud import storage

GS_BUCKET = getenv("GS_BUCKET")
GS_FOLDER = "sql-exports"
GS_EXPORT_PATH = f"gs://{GS_BUCKET}/{GS_FOLDER}"


def __sql_file_name(db: str, timestamp: datetime):
    return f"{db}-{timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.sql.gz"


def __sql_file_uri(db: str, timestamp: datetime):
    return f"{GS_EXPORT_PATH}/{__sql_file_name(db, timestamp)}"


def __export_source_db(service, project: str, timestamp: datetime, instance: str, db: str):
    context = {
        "exportContext": {
            "kind": "sql#exportContext",
            "fileType": "SQL",
            "uri": __sql_file_uri(db, timestamp),
            "databases": [db],
        }
    }

    return service.instances().export(project=project, instance=instance, body=context).execute()


def __import_target_db(service, project: str, timestamp: datetime, instance: str, db: str):
    context = {
        "importContext": {
            "kind": "sql#importContext",
            "fileType": "SQL",
            "uri": __sql_file_uri(db, timestamp),
            "database": db,
        }
    }

    return service.instances().import_(project=project, instance=instance, body=context).execute()


def __drop_db(service, project: str, instance: str, db: str):
    try:
        return service.databases().delete(project=project, instance=instance, database=db).execute()
    except HttpError as e:
        if e.resp.status == 404:
            return {"status": "DONE"}
        else:
            raise e


def __create_db(service, project: str, instance: str, db: str):
    database = {
        "name": db,
        "project": project,
        "instance": instance,
    }

    return service.databases().insert(project=project, instance=instance, body=database).execute()


def __update_export_permissions(file_name: str):
    client = storage.Client()
    file = client.get_bucket(GS_BUCKET).get_blob(f"{GS_FOLDER}/{file_name}")
    file.acl.user(getenv("TARGET_DB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT")).grant_read()
    file.acl.save()


def __delete_sql_file(file_name: str):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(GS_BUCKET)
    bucket.delete_blob(f"{GS_FOLDER}/{file_name}")


def __wait_for(operation_type, operation, service, project):
    if operation["status"] in ("PENDING", "RUNNING", "UNKNOWN"):
        print(f"{operation_type} operation in {operation['status']} status. Waiting for completion...")

        while operation['status'] != "DONE":
            sleep(1)
            operation = service.operations().get(project=project, operation=operation['name']).execute()

    print(f"{operation_type} operation completed!")


def clone_db(_):
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)

    # Project ID of the project that contains the instance to be exported.
    project = getenv('PROJECT_ID')

    # Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.
    source = {
        "instance": getenv("SOURCE_INSTANCE_ID"),
        "db": getenv("SOURCE_DB_NAME")
    }

    timestamp = datetime.utcnow()

    print(f"Exporting database {source['instance']}:{source['db']} to Cloud Storage...")
    operation = __export_source_db(service, project, timestamp, **source)

    __wait_for("Export", operation, service, project)

    print("Updating exported file permissions...")
    __update_export_permissions(__sql_file_name(source["db"], timestamp))
    print("Done.")

    target = {
        "instance": getenv("TARGET_INSTANCE_ID"),
        "db": getenv("TARGET_DB_NAME")
    }

    print(f"Dropping target database {target['instance']}:{target['db']}")
    operation = __drop_db(service, project, **target)
    __wait_for("Drop", operation, service, project)

    print(f"Creating database {target['instance']}:{target['db']}...")
    operation = __create_db(service, project, **target)
    __wait_for("Creation", operation, service, project)

    print(f"Importing data into {target['instance']}:{target['db']}...")
    operation = __import_target_db(service, project, timestamp, **target)
    __wait_for("Import", operation, service, project)

    print("Deleting exported SQL file")
    __delete_sql_file(__sql_file_name(source["db"], timestamp))
    print("Done.")
```

Things work perfectly fine until I'm trying to **import** the exported data into my target instance.

As it calls `import_`, the function fails with the following error:

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project_id>/instances/<instance_id>/import?alt=json returned "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.">
```

I have read about this error in many other Q&As here and on the web, but I can't figure out how to make things work.
Here's what I have done:

- The Cloud Function is run as my "Compute Engine default service account", which has the `Project Editor` role set in IAM
- The target Cloud SQL instance's service account is added in the bucket's permissions as a `Storage Object Admin`. I have tried various other roles combinations (legacy reader/owner, storage object viewer, ...) to no avail
- As you can see in the function's code, I am specifically granting read access to the target instance's service account for the exported file, and it is correctly reflected on the object's permissions in cloud storage:

[image: GCS object permissions]

- I have tried disabling object-level permissions for this bucket and made sure the permissions of my first point above were correctly set, but it did not work either

Interestingly, when I'm trying to manually import the same file on the same instance from the GCP Cloud SQL console, things work perfectly well.
After it's done, I can see that my exported file's permissions have been updated to include the instance's service account as a `Reader`, just as I have done in my code in the end to try and reproduce the behaviour.

So what am I missing here?
Which permissions should I set, for which service account, for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your code not with Cloud SQL.

When calling the `_import_target_db` function you are looking for a file that does not exist in your Cloud Storage bucket.

Getting into details:

You exported the database to your bucket with the name:

`gs://yourBucket/sql-exports/exportedDatabaseName-yyyy-mm-dd.sql.gz`

However, when your try to import it, the import function is looking for a file named:

`gs://yourBucket/sql-exports/importDatabaseName-yyyy-mm-dd.sql.gz`

This file does not exist in your bucket and for security reasons a `403 Forbidden` error is returned.

Comment: Yes, you’re absolutely right! We have spotted that afterwards and I forgot to update the question... the access permission threw me off and I did not question the validity of my code when it happened, making this a complicated case for nothing  Google’s response to « could there be a better error message » is that for security reasons, it’s better not to give away the information of « file not found » versus « no permission to access it », which makes sense. Anyway thanks for looking into it, good catch!

Comment: Wow, just had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried a lot of different things. Even after giving the DB-service-account owner-rights on the project, bucket and SQL-files it didn't worked while importing/exporting from/to other files always worked.

So I ended up renaming my import-file and surprisingly then it worked (the former filename was quite long and had underscores in it like in your example). But I cannot find anything in the documentation about such naming-limitations and at this point I can't even tell if this issue is related to the file-name or the usage of underscores. But it might be worth to try that.

Comment: Man, that's incredible :D
I've been on this subject for full month with Google's support, escalated to the engineers from the Cloud Functions team and we couldn't find the issue. The error message is clearly misleading and I guess there's a nice bug to be fixed there; I'm gonna follow-up with them with that workaround; thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The CloudSQL instance is running under a Google service account that is not a part of your project.

You need to find your instance's service account 
 - Cloud SQL-> *cluster name* ->Service account

[image]

Then, you take the above service account and give it write/read permission for the relevant bucket

Comment: That's what I meant when I said I had tried the following:
"The target Cloud SQL instance's service account is added in the bucket's permissions as a Storage Object Admin. I have tried various other roles combinations (legacy reader/owner, storage object viewer, ...) to no avail"